# Sharing files in the enterprise - a "private dropbox" with granular permissions

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I'm looking for an enterprise solution similar to Dropbox to share files across an organization. Ideally it should support:

1. Granular sharing of folders (specify group or individual users per group). We don't want GBs and GBs of data to be replicated to everyone. Each person should be synced to what they need exactly, but a hierarchy needs to be maintained in the folders.
2. Allow management from a centralized 'admin'
3. Possible integration to existing domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) nature of this question?

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" - We're a software shop. I want to increase our efficiency. Was looking for a commercial or Open source project to do the job that's all. If you think it's not relevant I can delete the post.

Comment: Well, as it stands it'll possibly get closed since it's not really *specific* to programming; it could apply to any number of professions. However, I'm just one opinion - you don't have to close it yourself on my behalf, but it may get closed if enough people vote to close it. I was just trying to encourage you to perhaps make it more specific to programming (although I'm not really sure how).